# Access full data in grouped dplyr summarize without relying on dplyr internals

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that is supposed to be used in a grouped `dplyr::summarise()`. I want to access *both* the data of each group *as well as* the full data. The former can easily be achieved with `dplyr::across()`. For the latter, I only see the option to rely on an internal function `mask <- dplyr:::peek_mask()` and then do `mask$full_data()`.

My question: Is there any way to access the full data without relying on an internal function?

Below is a simple example, the actual function is rather complex, but in its essence it compares the grouped data to the full data.

Added for clarification: Ideally, the user can call this function `foo` and it produces the result inside `dplyr::summarise` without the need of specifying further arguments or adding calls.

Any help appreciated.

```r
library(dplyr)

# function to be used inside summarize
foo <- function() {
  mask <- dplyr:::peek_mask() # replace this function without relying on dplyr internals
  full_data <- mask$full_data() 
  tibble(group_rows = nrow(across()),
         full_data = nrow(full_data))
}

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear) %>% 
 summarise(foo()) 
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    gear group_rows full_data
#>   <dbl>      <int>     <int>
#> 1     3         15        32
#> 2     4         12        32
#> 3     5          5        32
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: The actual function is rather complex but in its essence it compares the grouped data with the full data, and the challenge is to do this inside a function inside `summarise`.

Answer (score 1):

An option is `cur_data`

```
foo <- function() {
 
  tibble(group_rows = nrow(across()),
         full_data = nrow(cur_data())) 
        
}

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear) %>% 
 summarise(foo(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
 mutate(full_data  = sum(full_data))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   gear group_rows full_data
#  <dbl>      <int>     <int>
#1     3         15        32
#2     4         12        32
#3     5          5        32
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `cur_data` also give back the grouped data. Ideally I would like to create a function `foo` that creates said output inside`summarize` without specifying further arguments or adding calls.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Is there any issue with `peek_mask` function

Comment: I want to use this in a package and I think it is bad practice to rely on internal functions of packages that I do not maintain.

Comment: @TimTeaFan - I think this depends on the licence under which the other package is distributed. You could then just copy the source code and make it an internal function of your own package, with the proper acknowledgement of the other authors. just a thought   :)